# How to get all “li” elements of “ul” class in Selenium WebDriver - PageFactory specific

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3">
    <h4>Free Resources</h4>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="/ncert-solutions/ncert-solutions-class-10-maths">NCERT Solutions for Class 10 Maths</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/ncert-solutions/ncert-solutions-class-9-maths">NCERT Solutions for Class 9 Maths</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/ncert-solutions/ncert-solutions-class-10-science">NCERT Solutions for Class 10 Science</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/ncert-solutions/ncert-solutions-class-9-science">NCERT Solutions for Class 9 Science</a>
        </li>
        <!-- CBSE Previous Year Paper -->
        <li>
            <a href="/contents/question-solutions">CBSE Previous Year Paper</a>
        </li>
        <!-- RD Sharma solutions-->
        <li>
            <a href="/rd-sharma-solutions/rd-sharma-class-10-solutions">RD Sharma Class 10 Solutions</a>
        </li>
        <!-- Tutors SEO Pages-->
        <li>
            <a href="/tutors/home-tuition-teacher">Home Tuition</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/tutors/maths-tuition-teacher">Math Teacher</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/tutors/science-tuition-teacher">Science Teacher</a>
        </li>
    </ul>             
</div>
```

I have pasted the html I am working with. Just to make things more clear there exists two more div tags in the same hierarchy with the `class name = 'col-md-3 col-sm-3'`.

I found this question helpful ([How to get all "li" elements of "ul" class in Selenium WebDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32497998/how-to-get-all-li-elements-of-ul-class-in-selenium-webdriver)) but I wanted to know how to do the same using PageFactory ?.

Please help me here. I am thinking that I will find the root of the list `<div>` element (using `@FindBy` annotation) and do the looping for each `<a>` tag and return this list from the Element repository class for that web page. Is there a better way to do this? I specifically want PageFactory version of this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use @FindBys

like,

```
@FindBys(xpath)
List<WebElement> elements;
```

For example if have list of element under UL tag. Then your xpath will be `//ul/li/a` and you can use it in page factory as given below.

```
@FindBys(xpath="//ul/li/a")
public List<WebElement> elements;
```

You can call it in your script or method like, I assume the element is on homepage,

```
Home homePage = new HomePage(driver);
PageFactory.initElements(driver, homePage);
homePage.elements.get(0).click //to click on first element
```

or to iterate all elements and get the values as given below.

```
for(WebElement element:elements)
   sop(element.getText();
```

Comment: can you please elaborate? with some example?